# Installing Darknet on Windows 10 without OpenCV and CUDA (no GPU on own device): issues

Tags: darknet, darkflow

I have been trying to install Darknet on my own device (which runs on Windows 10) unsuccessfully. I am following the rough guide here: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/. However, it only contains the steps for a Linux configuration, so I have been checking out posts and videos about doing it on Windows.

Has anyone come across a relatively straightforward guide or YouTube video about how to install Darknet without the need to have a local GPU (as a dependency, CUDA requires GPU) that you have found particularly useful? I have been following a few (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saDipJR14Lc was pretty clear), but they all go through the CUDA installation as a must (where CUDA should be an optional dependency).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) GitHub repository for installing darknet. Refer to [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-compile-on-windows-using-cmake) section for installing it on Windows 10.

There is a detailed description provided on how to go about installing it on Windows 10 without GPU and OpenCV support

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I finally managed to get hold of a machine with NVIDIA GPU and have been following the instructions that you pointed me to. However, I get stuck at point 4: "Run command: python build\darknet\x64\data\voc\voc_label.py (to generate files: 2007_test.txt, 2007_train.txt, 2007_val.txt, 2012_train.txt, 2012_val.txt)". Perhaps this is a basic question/issue, but do I need to execute this line in my Windows 10 command prompt (it does not seem to be recognized as valid)? Many thanks again!

Comment: Ideally, it should work in windows command prompt, maybe you can try the same in Windows Powershell? What's the error exactly?

Comment: "run command..." I believe is used to set up files that you would use for training; Next step from there is to determine anchors; though that's really not helpful until you've trained a network a few times & understand the requirements to improve it without over constraint.

AlexeyB's github is the go-to place for anything darknet on Win10; so you're in the right place. try running the demo which performs yolo object detection using your webcam: Requires at min 3 command line arguments -datafile -config -weights
 FOR EX: darknet.exe detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! It seems like I have been able to install darknet successfully, however, I am still unable to train using the Pascal VOC data. I followed the instructions that @JiteshMalipeddi provided, but get an error in the cmd when executing "python build\darknet\x64\data\voc\voc_label.py". The error is: python: can't open file 'build\darknet\x64\data\voc\voc_label': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I don't get it as I do have that file (it exists) and it's located in the voc directory...

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I was able to successfully install Darknet using the following 3 lines of code in Powershell (after installing the required dependencies, with ninja this time around, as well as cloning the Alexey AB repository):

```
cd darknet
git pull 
.\build.ps1 -EnableCUDA -EnableCUDNN -EnableOPENCV -EnableOPENCV_CUDA -UseVCPKG
```

The discussions on the Discord forum were extremely helpful: https://discord.com/channels/741676058666860635/741676058666860639